# Need a link in Shopify that adds items to cart and redirects to checkout

Tags: shopify

I am attempting to add a "quick purchase" option for my products in Shopify. I'd like to have one link that adds qty:1 for a specific product ID and then redirects the user to check out.

Is it possible to create a query string that will accomplish this?

Comment: What you have tried so far please share your code

Answer (score 0):

Shopify has an inbuilt AJAX functionality for the purpose. Refer to the link: [Shopify's Ajax API](https://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/themes/can-i-use-ajax-api)